# How do I change the Terminal user name (Mac)?

Tags: terminal

Near the start of the Terminal window, you see Name1@Name2.

I am wondering how I can change Name1.  I have only been successful at changing Name2 so far.

Thanks!

Comment: What terminal? what OS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Source:https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username

The website above says to `sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername`

Comment: Doesn't work.  I forgot to mention I'm using a Mac.  That answer was also 10 years ago, not sure if that's relevant though.

Comment: Sorry in that case!